# Problem with retriving subnodes in simplexml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

if i have this xml :

```
<field name="gender" type="select1">
    <label>Gender</label>
    <item>
        <label>Male</label>
        <value>1</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <label>Female</label>
        <value>2</value>
    </item>
    <constraints>
        <required/>
    </constraints>
</field>
```

assume that i have to get each item tags and create a html form . how can i do that using simplexml document print_r of xml object shows this :

```
[item] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [label] => Male
                                    [value] => 1
                                )

                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [label] => Female
                                    [value] => 2
                                )

                        )
```

but in my code

```
foreach($xml as $field) 
    {
        $type = $xml->field[$i]->attributes()->type ; 
        $name = $xml->field[$i]->attributes()->name ;
        $required = $xml->field[$i]->constraints[0]->required[0] ;



            //checkboxes and radios 
            echo $xml->field[$i]->lable ; 
            //check the lable 
            if(is_array($xml->field[$i]->item))
            {
                echo 'yes it\'s a array ' ; 
            }






        $i++ ; 
    }
```

using this code

```
if ($type == 'select1' || $type == 'radio') {
        foreach ($field->item as $item) {
            echo "{$item->label} = {$item->value}\n";
        }
    }
```

actually there is another sets of field tag consist of item tags so second foreach loop will be ignored

```
 <field name="language" type="select">
            <label>Language(s)</label>
            <item>
                <label>English</label>
                <value>1</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                <label>French</label>
                <value>2</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                <label>Persian</label>
                <value>4</value>
            </item>
            <constraints/>
        </field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this:

```
$sxml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach ($sxml->field as $field) {
    $label = $field->label;
    $type = $field['type'];
    $name = $field['gender'];
    $required = isset($field->constraints->required);

    if ($type == 'select1' || $type == 'radio') {
        foreach ($field->item as $item) {
            echo "{$item->label} = {$item->value}\n";
        }
    }
}
```

If there are not any `<items>` nodes, the second `foreach` will be ignored. You don't have to explicitly check for it.

Comment: if i have more <items> nodes how do i check for it . because it's repeat other nodes on second foreach loop